# What's the difference between "m" and "make" when building Android source code

Tags: android, build, android-source

Here is the build doc:

https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building

Here is the code for building source code:

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_arm64-eng
m -j16

source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_arm64-eng
make -j16
```

**Question 1**

Is it the same when building with "`m -j16`" and "`make -j16`"?

**Question 2**

Here is the code for creating the distribution for `Android kernel`:

```
tools/bazel run //common:kernel_aarch64_dist -- --dist_dir=out/dist
```

How to create the distribution for "`lunch aosp_arm64-eng`"?

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_arm64-eng
m -j16
...<how to create distribution here> ...
```